# Why does Tensorflow multiclass-image-prediction not work when model is loaded?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagenet

I am currently trying to learn machine learning techniques and wanted to recreate a simple image recognition algorithm with tensorflow. Therefore I made two Python-files: One for training and one for prediction.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04
Used Python Version: 3.7
Used Numpy Version: 1.18.1
Used Tensorflow Version: 1.14 and 2.1.0 (outputs below are from Version 1.14)

My images are from http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/databases/pubfig/download/#dev
The set consists of about 3000 images of cropped faces from 60 people.

train_model.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import pathlib
import hashlib
import os
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

people = pd.read_csv("dev_people.txt")

image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2, rotation_range=45, zoom_range=0.2)

IMG_HEIGHT = 128
IMG_WIDTH = 128
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_TRAIN = 100
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = round(NUM_TRAIN) // BATCH_SIZE
VAL_STEPS = 20
NUM_EPOCHS = 3

train_data = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    directory="persons-cropped",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset="training")

labels = train_data.class_indices
labels = {v: k for k, v in labels.items()}

with open("labels.json", "w") as labels_file:
    labels_file.write(json.dumps(labels))

validation_data = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    directory="persons-cropped",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset="validation")

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
    input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3),
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet"
)

base_model.trainable = False

maxpool_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(60, activation="sigmoid")
dropout_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base_model,
    maxpool_layer,
#   dropout_layer,
    prediction_layer
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

model.summary()

model.fit(
    train_data,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    validation_steps=None,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    workers=6,
    verbose=2
)

model.save("model.h5")
```

Output:

```
Found 2431 images belonging to 60 classes.
Found 573 images belonging to 60 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py:1251: calling VarianceScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
2020-01-25 22:23:40.036326: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2599985000 Hz
2020-01-25 22:23:40.036657: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x6b81c60 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-01-25 22:23:40.036789: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-01-25 22:23:40.615771: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:180: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Model) (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d (Global (None, 1280)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 60)                76860
=================================================================
Total params: 2,334,844
Trainable params: 76,860
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/3
2020-01-25 22:23:55.995833: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 154140672 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2020-01-25 22:23:56.730363: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 156905472 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2020-01-25 22:24:02.782372: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 154140672 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2020-01-25 22:24:03.531172: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 156905472 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2020-01-25 22:24:09.474692: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 154140672 exceeds 10% of system memory.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:788: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 4 bytes but only got 0.
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
76/76 - 602s - loss: 0.3851 - acc: 0.9097 - val_loss: 0.1812 - val_acc: 0.9495
Epoch 2/3
76/76 - 616s - loss: 0.1480 - acc: 0.9757 - val_loss: 0.1732 - val_acc: 0.9544
Epoch 3/3
76/76 - 627s - loss: 0.1452 - acc: 0.9760 - val_loss: 0.1767 - val_acc: 0.9516
```

It says the model has an accuracy score of about 95 % which is very good and should be no problem for predicting images now. However, this is the prediction file:

predict_image.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib
import pathlib
import hashlib
import os
import sys
import cv2
import json
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL
import skimage
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

IMG_HEIGHT = 128
IMG_WIDTH = 128

def load_image(filename):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(filename, target_size=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT))
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0) / 255
    return img

from glob import glob
class_names = glob("persons-cropped/*")
class_names = sorted(class_names)

labels_file = open("labels.json", "r")
labels = json.loads(labels_file.read())

print(labels)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

model.summary()

img = load_image(sys.argv[1])

predictions = model.predict(img, verbose=1)
prediction = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)

print(predictions)
print(prediction)
map_labels = np.vectorize(lambda i: labels[str(i)])
print(map_labels(prediction))
```

Output: When using a Zach Braff image:

```
{'0': 'Abhishek Bachan', '1': 'Alex Rodriguez', '2': 'Ali Landry', '3': 'Alyssa Milano', '4': 'Anderson Cooper', '5': 'Anna Paquin', '6': 'Audrey Tautou', '7': 'Barack Obama', '8': 'Ben Stiller', '9': 'Christina Ricci', '10': 'Clive Owen', '11': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', '12': 'Daniel Craig', '13': 'Danny Devito', '14': 'David Duchovny', '15': 'Denise Richards', '16': 'Diane Sawyer', '17': 'Donald Faison', '18': 'Ehud Olmert', '19': 'Faith Hill', '20': 'Famke Janssen', '21': 'Hugh Jackman', '22': 'Hugh Laurie', '23': 'James Spader', '24': 'Jared Leto', '25': 'Julia Roberts', '26': 'Julia Stiles', '27': 'Karl Rove', '28': 'Katherine Heigl', '29': 'Kevin Bacon', '30': 'Kiefer Sutherland', '31': 'Kim Basinger', '32': 'Mark Ruffalo', '33': 'Meg Ryan', '34': 'Michelle Trachtenberg', '35': 'Michelle Wie', '36': 'Mickey Rourke', '37': 'Miley Cyrus', '38': 'Milla Jovovich', '39': 'Nicole Richie', '40': 'Rachael Ray', '41': 'Robert Gates', '42': 'Ryan Seacrest', '43': 'Sania Mirza', '44': 'Sarah Chalke', '45': 'Sarah Palin', '46': 'Scarlett Johansson', '47': 'Seth Rogen', '48': 'Shahrukh Khan', '49': 'Shakira', '50': 'Stephen Colbert', '51': 'Stephen Fry', '52': 'Steve Carell', '53': 'Steve Martin', '54': 'Tracy Morgan', '55': 'Ty Pennington', '56': 'Viggo Mortensen', '57': 'Wilmer Valderrama', '58': 'Zac Efron', '59': 'Zach Braff'}
2020-01-25 22:58:05.582049: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2599985000 Hz
2020-01-25 22:58:05.582514: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x618f910 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-01-25 22:58:05.582653: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-01-25 22:58:06.454565: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 999ms/sample
[[3.23683023e-04 6.47217035e-04 3.90201807e-04 2.69789696e-02
  2.17908323e-02 1.53781831e-01 4.79090214e-03 8.64863396e-04
  1.11432403e-01 8.87395382e-01 3.30170989e-03 2.17252970e-03
  1.78458661e-01 1.09243691e-02 1.47551298e-04 2.62927115e-02
  3.22049320e-01 2.69562006e-04 9.11523938e-01 2.44581699e-03
  7.65213370e-03 2.90286541e-03 1.01376325e-01 6.43432140e-05
  4.43832874e-02 3.94093990e-03 6.90050423e-02 7.47233629e-04
  1.05589628e-03 8.04662704e-07 3.76045704e-03 4.28827941e-01
  1.20029151e-02 1.77664489e-01 5.27173281e-04 2.45797634e-03
  5.89579344e-03 9.46103930e-01 2.79089808e-03 2.09265649e-02
  2.83238888e-02 4.86207008e-03 8.15459788e-02 1.30202770e-02
  1.50602162e-02 1.33922696e-03 1.24056339e-02 5.76970875e-02
  2.65627503e-02 5.18084109e-01 4.89562750e-04 3.15269828e-03
  4.88847494e-04 2.13665128e-01 1.40489936e-02 2.93705761e-02
  5.01989722e-02 1.21492555e-03 1.62564263e-01 2.91267484e-01]]
[37]
['Miley Cyrus']
```

The prediction algorithm is wrong all the time. If I use other Zach Braff images, the output stays the same for the same picture of course, but in 10 test cases it was never Zach Braff but always a different person. (Not only Miley Cyrus, but also Shakira, Steve Carell, ...)

This pattern appears for any class I use as input here.

I did not find any helpful advice on the internet and tried like every parameter combination I can image could work. I also used two versions of Tensorflow and made sure that all libraries are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I believe you are getting strange predictions because your data distribution has 60 classes of people while your model is compiled with a loss function that is set to binary crossentropy.

Binary crossentropy is used to determine a max of 2 classes. What you need to do is change the loss function to categorical crossentropy.

```
 model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE),
 loss="categorical_crossentropy", # here
 metrics=["accuracy"]
)
```